# Get the npm dependancies for a linux system on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm making a deployement script, the last missing piece is the node_modules managment.

Is it possible to retrieve every thing listed on my package.json for a linux system on my windows system (the deployment script is running on a windows machine).
And then I'll send it to my linux server over ssh. (due to network limitations I cannot run npm install on the server)

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are save as long as none of your deps is native module which requires a compilation using node gyp since it would mean the module wouldn't run on Linux. Your best bet in that case is to use virtual machine with the Linux version same as on your server.

Comment: Work constraint : deployment script has to be on a windows machine.